# Python dictionary combined keys which are segment ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys

```
segments = { (0,13):'Bike segment', (22,217):'Car segment' }
```

How to find the correct segment where an item: 122 is part of?

```
print(segments[122]) - KeyError
```

Clearly not the way of doing this so read about ranges, ok, seems legit:

```
segments = { range(0,13):'Bike segment', range(22,217):'Car segment' }
print(segments[122]) - KeyError

segments = { (if 0<= value <=13) :'Bike segment', (if 22<=value<=217):'Car segment' } # not working
```

How to efficiently resolve a value by its key without iterating trough its entire list???

Comment: You can't really do that - unless you can resolve a value to its bucket up-front (i.e. map from `122` -> `(22, 217)`) you're stuck with a `O(n)` scan to find the range/tuple the new value fits into. If you're doing this a lot it might be worth building the key-finding map `{122: (22, 217), ...}`.

Comment: @Jesperrekuh, if one of the below responses answer your question, feel free to accept (tick on left) so other users know it's been tested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are representing ranges as tuple dictionary keys, this would work:

```
segments = {(0, 13): 'Bike segment', (22, 217): 'Car segment'}

[v for k, v in segments.items() if 122 in range(*k)]

# ['Car segment']
```

If your ranges are not mutually exclusive, you may get more than one element. If your input does not exist in one of the ranges, you will have an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
segments={}
for i in range(0,13)    :
    segments[i] = 'Bike segment'

for i in range(22,217) :
    segments[i] = 'Car segment' 

print(segments[122])
```

Output

> Car segment